# Strong operator continuity implies weak operator continuity for functionals

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

What is an easy way to see that $\phi:B(\mathcal{H})\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ being a strong operator continuous linear functional implies it is weak operator continuous? I must've thought of this before but for some reason I am blanking now.

Comment: Don’t really know functional analysis but sounds something along the lines of https://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeakConvergence.html

Comment: @JoeShmo.   The terminology is a bit misleading. The so called "weak topology" (defined for every normed vector space) is distinct from the "weak operator topology", which is only defined on spaces of operators.

Answer (score 2):

Given $\phi :B(\mathcal H) \to  {\mathbb C}$ continuous in the strong operator topology,  by definition (almost) there are vectors $\xi _1,  \xi _2,  \ldots ,  \xi _n\in \mathcal H$, such that
$$
  |\phi (T)|\leq  \sup_i \|T(\xi _i)\|,\quad \forall T∈ B(\mathcal H) .
  $$
From this it is easy to show that $\phi $ factors as $\phi =\psi \circ u$, where
$$
  u:T\in  B(\mathcal H) \mapsto  \big (T(\xi _1), T(\xi _2), \ldots , T(\xi _n)\big )\in  \mathcal H^n,
  $$
and $\psi $ is a continuos linear functional on  $\mathcal H^n$.

By a slightly modified version of the Riesz representation theorem,  any such $\psi $ is necessarily of the form
$$
  \psi (\zeta _1, \zeta _2, \ldots ,  \zeta _n) = \sum_{i=1}^n\langle \zeta _i, \eta _i\rangle ,
  $$
for some $(\eta _1, \eta _2, \ldots ,  \eta _n) \in \mathcal H^n$.  Consequently
$$
  \phi (T)= \psi (u(T)) = \psi \big (T(\xi _1), T(\xi _2), \ldots , T(\xi _n)\big ) =  \sum_{i=1}^n\big \langle T(\xi _i), \eta _i\big \rangle ,
  $$
proving that $\phi $ is continuous in the weak operator topology.

---

Edit:. Here is an explanation of why does $\phi$ factor as stated above.

**Lemma**.  Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces, let $u:X\to Y$ be a bounded linear map, and let $\phi:X\to\mathbb C$ be a continuous linear functional. Suppose that
$$|\phi(x)|\le C\|u(x)\|, \quad \forall x\in X,
$$
where $C$ is a constant.
Then there exists a continuous linear functional $\psi$ on $Y$ such that $\phi=\psi\circ u$.

*Proof*.  Let $R$ be the range of $u$.  For every $y\in R$, write $y=u(x)$, for some $x$ in $X$, and define
$$\psi(y)=\phi(x).$$
To see that the definition does not depend on the choice of $x$, suppose that also $y=u(x')$, where $x'\in X$.
Then
$$
|\phi(x)-\phi(x')|=|\phi(x-x')|\le $$$$
\le C\|u(x-x')\| =0.
$$
Another application of the hypothesis shows that
$\psi$ is a continuous linear functional on $R$.  Finally we may use Hahn-Banach to extend $\psi$ to the whole of $Y$.  QED

Comment: Can you spell out the first statement? Why are there finitely many such $\xi_i$?

Comment: The obvious implication is WOT closed $\Rightarrow$ SOT closed.  For the reverse implication you have to do some work, namely answer your question!

Comment: @Berci, Since $\phi $ is continuous,  there is a neighborhood $V$ of zero  such that for every $T$ in $V$,  one
has that $|\phi (T)|<1$.  By definition of the strong operator topology,  $V$ contains the intersection of finitely many
sub-basic sets,  i.e. sets of the form
  $$
  V_{\xi _i, \varepsilon _i}= \{T\in  B(\mathcal H): \|T(\xi _i)\|<\varepsilon _i\},
  $$
  say,  for $i=1,\ldots ,n$.
  By replacing $\xi _i$ with $\xi _i/\varepsilon _i$ we may assume that $\varepsilon _i=1$.  Consequently
  $$
  \sup_{1\leq i\leq n} \|T(\xi _i)\|<1 \ \Rightarrow \ |\phi (T)|<1 .
  $$

Comment: From this it is easy to show that   $|\phi (T)|\leq  \sup_i \|T(\xi _i)\|$.

Comment: @SihOASHoihd.  Why is it that SOT closed implies WOT closed?  This is equivalent to your question.

Comment: @Ruy you’re 100% right, I don’t know what I was thinking

Comment: @Ruy I am still trying to figure out why $\phi$ factors the way you claim. I am sure your right but I am not seeing it

Comment: @SihOASHoihd.  I tried to explain the factorization in my updated answer.  Please let me know whether it is understandable!

Comment: @Ruy That makes sense to me, thanks